# XSLT - append sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, append, flat, siblings

I'm trying to use XSLT to append `context-param` as last sibling. There's no common parent element so the task is a little bit harder.

I'd like to append following element:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>miku</param-name>
    <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
</context-param>
```

as the last `context-param` element (eg. all `context-param` elements must be next to each other, they can't be scattered anywhere in xml) in following xml:

```
<web-app>
  <not_interesting_element1/>
  <not_interesting_element2/>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>not_interesting_param_key1</param-name>
    <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>not_interesting_param_key2</param-name>
    <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>parameterThatsGuaranteedToBeHere</param-name>
    <param-value>someValue</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <not_interesting_element3/>
  <not_interesting_element4/>
  <!-- ... servlets, ... -->
</web-app>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<web-app>
  <not_interesting_element1/>
  <not_interesting_element2/>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>not_interesting_param_key1</param-name>
    <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>not_interesting_param_key2</param-name>
    <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>parameterThatsGuaranteedToBeHere</param-name>
    <param-value>someValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>miku</param-name>
      <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <not_interesting_element3/>
  <not_interesting_element4/>
  <!-- ... servlets, ... -->
</web-app>
```

How could I do it please?

Comment: Append to what? Please, edit the question and provide the XML document and the particular siblings nodes, to which you want to append te `context-param` element. Then notify me via a comment.

Comment: Please post samples of input and desired output XML illustrating the problem.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pElemToAdd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>miku</param-name>
        <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
    </context-param>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="context-param[last()]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$pElemToAdd"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<web-app>
    <not_interesting_element1/>
    <not_interesting_element2/>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>not_interesting_param_key1</param-name>
        <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>not_interesting_param_key2</param-name>
        <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>parameterThatsGuaranteedToBeHere</param-name>
        <param-value>someValue</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <not_interesting_element3/>
    <not_interesting_element4/>
    <!-- ... servlets, ... -->
</web-app>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<web-app>
   <not_interesting_element1/>
   <not_interesting_element2/>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>not_interesting_param_key1</param-name>
      <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>not_interesting_param_key2</param-name>
      <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>parameterThatsGuaranteedToBeHere</param-name>
      <param-value>someValue</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
      <param-name>miku</param-name>
      <param-value>kawaii</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <not_interesting_element3/>
   <not_interesting_element4/><!-- ... servlets, ... -->
</web-app>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is".
2. There is a single template, overriding the identity template. This template matches the last `context-param` element of all `context-param` elements that are children of their parent.
3. In the overriding template two actions are performed; the current node is copied by a call to the identity rule; then the element to be appended is copied to the output. For convenience and flexibility, we assume that the element to be appended is passed as a parameter to the transformation.

Comment: Thank you. This works if I append one element. If I do it repeatedly, the element that's appended also rewrites previous element so it looks like there last `context-path` element is removed and two new elements are appended.

Comment: @woky: If you want to append more than one node, you have to specify the complete node-set to be appended in the parameter.