# Create XSLT variable that is a copy of XML, append nodes, loop through variable and output values

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <query>
        <row> 
            <Name>Ed</Name> 
            <ID>11</ID> 
        </row> 
        <row> 
            <Name>Chad</Name> 
            <ID>12</ID> 
        </row> 
        <row> 
            <Name>Jason</Name> 
            <ID>13</ID> 
        </row>
    </query>
</xml>
```

I want to use XSLT to do the following:

```
<create a variable that is a copy of the entire XML document>
<append an additional node to the XML in the variable>
<loop through each <row> inside the new variable and output the name and ID>
```

So inside the variable, I want to end up with this XML

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <query>
        <row> 
            <Name>Ed</Name> 
            <ID>11</ID> 
        </row> 
        <row> 
            <Name>Chad</Name> 
            <ID>12</ID> 
        </row> 
        <row> 
            <Name>Jason</Name> 
            <ID>13</ID> 
        </row>
        <row> 
            <Name>Mark</Name> 
            <ID>14</ID> 
        </row>
    </query>
</xml>
```

and end up with this output:

```
Ed
11

Chad
12

Jason
13

Mark 
14
```

The reason I want to use a variable is because I'm using the Microsoft Word plug-in for Oracle BI Publisher. This plug-in allows you to create a template using XSLT that takes the XML results from a query to produce a PDF file; its basically a fancy mail-merge. There are some rows that are not returned by the query, though, that I need to add into the XML document before I loop through the data.

Because of the nature of the the template, I don't think I can use an external XSL file to modify the XML before I process it. So, the only thing I can think of is to create a variable with all the XML, append the additional nodes that would not be returned by the query to the XML in the variable, and then loop through that that variable to output the values. I've been searching on SO and have found posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227347/xslt-append-sibling) but I don't want the result to be a modified XML file, I want it to be something I can use within the template immediately like a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/query">
    <xsl:variable name="xmlFragment">
      <query>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <row>
          <Name>Mark</Name>
          <ID>14</ID>
        </row>
      </query>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($xmlFragment)/query/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The variable contains an XML fragment, that needs to be converted to a node-set to be used in the `for-each` - this is done with the Microsoft-specific extension function `msxsl:node-set()`, other XSLT processor have equivalent functions.

(I am not totally sure why you need the variable - I think that the job could be done directly, but in any case the code above creates the variable first and then enumerates on it)